# WHERE a AND b returns just WHERE b

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables which I want to join and return only those records which:

1. Have the same value with other records in one of the columns.
2. Have certain values in other column.

These are my requests:

List only those records which have the same value with other records in grnz column:

```
SELECT * 
FROM violations.violation_decrees AS vd
JOIN violations.violations_reports AS vr
ON vd.violation_id = vr.violation_id 
WHERE vd.grnz IN (SELECT grnz 
               FROM violations.violation_decrees AS vd
               GROUP BY vd.grnz HAVING COUNT(id) > 1)
ORDER BY vd.grnz
```

List only those records which have violation_status_id equal to 10 or 11

```
SELECT * 
FROM violations.violation_decrees AS vd
JOIN violations.violations_reports AS vr
ON vd.violation_id = vr.violation_id 
WHERE vr.violation_status_id IN (10,11)
ORDER BY vd.grnz
```

But when I try to combine them

```
SELECT * 
FROM violations.violation_decrees AS vd
JOIN violations.violations_reports AS vr
ON vd.violation_id = vr.violation_id 
WHERE vd.grnz IN (SELECT grnz 
               FROM violations.violation_decrees AS vd
               GROUP BY vd.grnz HAVING COUNT(id) > 1)
AND vr.violation_status_id IN (10,11)
ORDER BY vd.grnz
```

condition

```
vd.grnz IN (SELECT grnz 
                   FROM violations.violation_decrees AS vd
                   GROUP BY vd.grnz HAVING COUNT(id) > 1)
```

is completely ignored and output is similar to request N 2.

Any advice?

P.S. sample [image]

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Hi, please add some sample schema and data **as text** so that someone answering can run it themselves and reproduce the problem. See [mcve] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for why and how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the building of the schema I found an error: I was picking duplicates before implementing the value filter.

Here is the correct request:

```
SELECT vr.violation_status_id, vd.* 
FROM violations.violation_decrees AS vd
JOIN violations.violations_reports AS vr
ON vd.violation_id = vr.violation_id 
WHERE vd.grnz IN (SELECT vd.grnz 
               FROM violations.violation_decrees AS vd
               JOIN violations.violations_reports AS vr
               ON vd.violation_id = vr.violation_id 
               WHERE vr.violation_status_id IN (10,11)
               GROUP BY vd.grnz HAVING COUNT(vd.grnz) > 1)
AND vr.violation_status_id IN (10,11)               
ORDER BY vd.grnz
```